# HTML video height via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I´m making a website for a client, where there is an autoplay video on the center of the website. The video changes by clicking on and element in slider. 
**Straight to the problem**: 
 Client want to have half of the slider always visible as youcan see here [http://imgur.com/a/Esi0z](https://imgur.com/a/Esi0z).
What i did is i took the height of the **window** and set height of the video: **window.height - 200px**. 
 Video is in the div element where did i put the **volume controll button** which i want to be always at the right side of the video. What i did is that i set the width and height of the parent element via javascript to the height and width of video, but **container is always a bit bigger and have weird margin**. http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/03/09/58c1b3cd01c1a.png Not sure how to fix this. 
 I'm very thankfull for every answer.

```
  // change the video height
  $('#video').height($(window).height()-200);
  $('.video-div').height($('#video').height()).width($('#video').width());


<div class="video">
  <div class="video-div">
    <div class="volume-bg"><img src="img/video/volume-n.png" alt="volume" class="volume"></div>
    <img src="img/video/pause.png" alt="play button" class="play-control">
    <video id="video" autoplay preload="none" muted="true" poster="img/video/video.png">
     <source src="video/urazove_pojisteni_final.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Works pretty fine in Mozilla.

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: A question involving rogue margins and video heights should have styles included. Don't forget to add CSS to your [mcve].